# golang profile with pprof, how to get hit count not duration?

Tags: go, profile, pprof

how to get hit count like:

```
(pprof) top
Total: 2525 samples
     298  11.8%  11.8%      345  13.7% runtime.mapaccess1_fast64
     268  10.6%  22.4%     2124  84.1% main.FindLoops
```

not, durations like:

```
(pprof) top
2220ms of 3080ms total (72.08%)
Dropped 72 nodes (cum <= 15.40ms)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 111 (cum >= 60ms)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    1340ms 43.51% 43.51%     1410ms 45.78%  runtime.cgocall_errno
```

env: I using golang1.4, add below codes.

```
defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
f, err := os.Create("innercpu.pprof")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `go tool pprof -callgrind -output callgrind.out innercpu.pprof` to generate callgrind data out of your collected profiling data. Which you can then visualise with [qcachegrind/kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/). It'll display call counts.